# curl Couldn't connect to server

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl, payment-gateway

I have been trying to connect to the Payment gateway API with CURL for last two days that return  JSON data. But every time I call it, it give following error

> cURL Error #:Failed to connect to api.sandbox.vm.co.mz port 18352
> after 813 ms: Couldn't connect to server

My curl code is :

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, 
  array(
    CURLOPT_PORT => "18352",
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.sandbox.vm.co.mz:18352/ipg/v1x/c2bPayment/singleStage/",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($fields),
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
      'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
      'Authorization' =>  'Bearer ' . $this->getToken(),
      'origin' => 'developer.mpesa.vm.co.mz',
      'Connection' => 'keep-alive'
    )
  )
);
```

My payment gateway documentation url is [Documentation Link](https://developer.mpesa.vm.co.mz/documentation/)

When I call this api in postmanor run in local  it gives the response which i want but when it call from the server curl coudn't find the server of api.

What do I wrong in this

Please give any solution

Comment: try `https`, its unlikely a payment gateway would use http

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Although it is very likely the `http` request would be redirected to `https`.

Comment: sorry for the HTTP I forgot to change this to HTTPS. I am using HTTPS in URL not HTTP

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE

It is not unusual for a gateway to not respond when it suspects an malicious or insecure request.

The doc says: `Authorization: Bearer (Encoded API Key)`
Make sure the key is Base64 encoded and then encrypted.

I am assuming you did these steps in the getToken().

- Generate a decoded Base64 string from the Public Key
- Generate an instance of an RSA cipher and use the decoded Base64 string as the input
- Encode the API Key with the RSA cipher and digest as Base64 string format

You may want to look at your outgoing header to see if what is be transmitted is what you expect.

Add this option

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
```

Retrieve the request header after curl_exec().

```
echo curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT
```

These sometimes come in handy when troubleshooting:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,true);

if (curl_errno($ch)){echo curl_error($ch);}
```

END OF UPDATE

Your headers will not work like that.

Use this:

```
$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
$headers[] = 'Authorization: Bearer xxxxx';
$headers[] = 'origin: developer.mpesa.vm.co.mz';
$headers[] = 'Connection: keep-alive';
```

You have `CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,` but you do not have `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION =>true,` making the former moot.

The `FOLLOWLOCATION` option would also eliminate the issue mentioned by @LawrenceCherone .   
`CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`  should be included in every curl request.
is incorrect.

The error  you are getting kinda says `CURLOPT_PORT => "18352",` is incorrect that is if the URL is correct.

Without access to the documentation my ability to help is limited.

Why their documentation is password protected is beyond my comprehension.  
I have to question whether I'd do business with this firm based on stupid stuff like this.

I click on the API link and get this:

[image]

Comment: Hi,
First of all Thanks for your answer, this is not working in my code. The URL is correct because when it's called from the postman response is received but not from my code.

I have checked by removing CURLOPT_PORT => "18352" but this is not an issue because the port no is already used in the URL and the URL is correct according to the brief documentation
and the api's full documentation required the login details .